# Cannot INSERT INTO from my form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, insert

I have this form

```
<form method="post" action="new_announcement.php">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Create New Announcement</legend>
Subject :<input type="text" style="float-offset: !important;" name="subject" required="required" /><br>
Content :<br />
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="content"></textarea>   </br></br> 
<input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

and I want to store the data from my form into a table in my database.

My **INSERT INTO** code is this...

```
<?php

include_once 'header.php';

$username = $_SESSION["username"];

if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO announcements (author,subject,content) VALUES ('$username','$subject','$content')";
}

?>
```

What I am doing wrong and it does not store the data in my database.
My database table is the below...

```
CREATE TABLE announcements
(
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    author varchar(200),
    subject varchar(200),
    content varchar(3000),
    timestamp int(11) unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id,author)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: Where does timestamp get its value?

Comment: can you echo $sqlinsert

Comment: @WorkSmarter doesn't it work automatically when i am entering an input?

Comment: Are you even executing the query? writing it in a string only is usually insufficient

Comment: @RajnikantSharma where do you want to echo it inside the if isset because if i do it inside the if then i didnt get something

Comment: inside of isset, i need to check if query is ok

Comment: @RajnikantSharma i did it and i dont get a result

Comment: @niklakis where you execute your query. like mysql_query($sqlinsert );

Comment: then var_dump($_POST);

Comment: @RajnikantSharma you want me to echo that?

Comment: @NavjotSingh what do you mean ?

Comment: no need echo just var_dump($_POST);

Comment: The timestamp definition needs to read like this logtime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Where you are specifying the default value.  Note: using timestamp as a column name should be done with care. Probably place in brackets due to it being a keyword.  Take a look at this post for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962757/when-is-a-timestamp-auto-updated

Comment: @RajnikantSharma i did this.... if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
    var_dump($_POST);
   ....
}
...
nothing happened

Comment: Nothing is going to happen to the DB with this code. It isn't being sent to the DB as @dvhh stated.

Comment: @chris85 I removed it and still does not work

Comment: where are the database connection script

Comment: Removed what? You need to add to it.

Comment: @chris85 I removed the timestamp column from the database just to see if it will work without it

Comment: @RajnikantSharma i include it in the header.php

Comment: Yes and as I and dvhh stated this code isnt being sent to your DB. You need to make a connection then execute your query. You're doing neither.

Comment: @chris85 i have a connection with my database because at the begining of the code i have include_once 'header.php';

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli libraries to work with the database

Comment: Okay so you got a connection. You're not using it with that query though...

Comment: Please specify how you open your database connection and someone could provide an answer

Comment: @dvhh i access my database from the include_once 'header.php'

Comment: please update you question to include the relevant line in the `header.php` where you open the connection, if possible **don't forget to replace the username and password with dummy values**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue 1. Your form doesn't have an input named "username". So your `if(isset($_POST['username']))` will never match. If you expect a username from the form you'll need to make one. If the session is set and correct (which it sounds like it is) use it. Issue 2. The connection isn't being used in the query (as the question stated). Here's updated navjot answer.

```
<?php
   include_once 'header.php';
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION["username"]);
   if(!empty($_POST)){
   if(isset($username)) {
        $subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
        $content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
        $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO announcements (author,subject,content) VALUES ('$username','$subject','$content')";
$execute = mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
   }
}
?>
```

Issue 3. This was SQL injectible, never trust user input. Issue 4. mysql functions are out of date you should switch over to mysqli or pdo.

There's tons of other threads on these topics though.

If you sanitize the `username` when you store it to the session that might be fine without the real escape.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in $username

Comment: now it says undefined index for subject and content

Comment: Run `print_r($_POST);` are they there?

Comment: where should i write it , inside the if() or after the if

Comment: In the `if`. You're processing the form when trying this right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73995/discussion-between-chris85-and-niklakis).

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute query. try this

```
 <?php

        include_once 'header.php';

        $username = $_SESSION["username"];

        if(isset($_POST['username']))
        {
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $content = $_POST['content'];

            $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO announcements (author,subject,content) VALUES ('$username','$subject','$content')";
    $execute = mysql_query($sqlinsert) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: add this below $sqlinsert line $result = mysql_query($sqlinsert);

Comment: Are you getting post data into Query?

Comment: have you selected db in your connection script like this mysql_select_db('yourdb') or die ('Database connection failed');

Comment: @RajnikantSharma if i add what you said i get this .. Undefined variable: sqlinsert

Comment: @RajnikantSharma i dont think that there is a problem with the connection because i am using the include_once code and into others pages and it works fine

Comment: You don't have a `POST username`. Remove that check or check `$username`. I don't know how you'd get into that conditional with the code provided.

Comment: @chris85 if i echo $username i get the logged in user

Comment: Yea? Look at your code though you're not using that variable.

`$username = $_SESSION["username"];

        if(isset($_POST['username']))`

Comment: @chris85 what is your suggestion for my if(isset($_POST['WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE']))