# How to make a column update timestamp automatically based on update on selected columns only?

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, can we use updated_at column to update the timestamp automatically based on updates done on only a selected few columns than all the columns of that table?

Ex: If my Table t1 has columns a,b,c and an updated_at column.

I want updated_at to be updated only when columns b and c are updated and not column a. Can this be done in MySQL by altering the updated_at column??

Edit this is not a duplicate of [When is a timestamp (auto) updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962757/when-is-a-timestamp-auto-updated)

And I cant use a trigger because there are lot of bulk updates that happen all the time than single row updates. So, there is an essential degradation of update-times.

Comment: You can accomplish this using a trigger.

Comment: But triggers will slow down on bulk updates right? any alternatives?