# set current_timestamp only on inserting a new row

Tags: mysql, date, sql-update, sql-insert, create-table

column `date` is `timestamp` - default value - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

I choose this because want a current datetime on `inserting` a new row.

But is is changed each time when another column is updated.

Is there a way to keep `current_timestamp` only on inserting a new row **and not** on updating another columns?

Comment: Why would a default value have anything to do with what happens during an update?  I thought a default value is only relevant for an insert.

Comment: Show your `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, no it is changed each time another column is changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is a timestamp (auto) updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962757/when-is-a-timestamp-auto-updated)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `TIMESTAMP` column updates automatically on every update. A `DATETIME` column doesn't.

You want:

```
your_column DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This lets you specify a default value at the time of insertion, like you would for any column, but because it's not a `TIMESTAMP` anymore it will not continue to update itself with each future `UPDATE`.

Comment: `This lets you specify a default value at the time of insertion  like you would for any column` - pls explain - if I specify something at the time of insertion - it's not a default.

Comment: The `DEFAULT` keyword is what specifies the default value at the time of insertion. If you omit the column in your `INSERT`, then `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is what will go in that column.

Answer (score 1):

From  [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) :

> An auto-updated column is automatically updated to the current timestamp when the value of any other column in the row is changed from its current value. An auto-updated column remains unchanged if all other columns are set to their current values. To prevent an auto-updated column from updating when other columns change, explicitly set it to its current value. To update an auto-updated column even when other columns do not change, explicitly set it to the value it should have (for example, set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).

So you to avoid the `my_date_col` column to auto-update on UPDATE, you want to explicitly preserve its value, like :

```
UPDATE my_table SET my_col1 = 'foo', my_col2 = 'bar', my_date_col = my_date_col
WHERE ...
```

Comment: thanks, I see, but must say - that's a pre-historical way of programming

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `moufa`; -- where `moufa` is the name of the table in the example
```

you will be able to see something like this

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field | Type        | Collation | Null | Key | Default             | Extra                         | Privileges                      | Comment |
+-------+-------------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| id    | smallint(6) | NULL      | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| ts    | timestamp   | NULL      | NO   |     | current_timestamp() | on update current_timestamp() | select,insert,update,references |         |
+-------+-------------+-----------+------+-----+---------------------+-------------------------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

The problem is on the `ts` field the `Extra`. To check your the table run

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `moufa`;
```

The most common case like [GMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10676716/gmb) posted the column has been auto-updated.

Now to avoid further cases like this, you should explicitly define the the default value for the column.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `moufa`; -- just for the example
CREATE TABLE `moufa`( 
    `id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `ts` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
```

Or rather than dropping and recreating a table

```
ALTER TABLE `moufa`
  MODIFY COLUMN `ts` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: `MODIFY COLUMN `ts` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;` - it already has that values?

Comment: what is the Extra after you run SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `x`; ?

Comment: extra for date column is empty

Comment: did you try to update it again I mean
`UPDATE \`x\` SET \`field1\` = 123 WHERE \`id\` = x;` Did it change the timestamp again? Normally it shouldn't as long as it is not defined