# Date column updating in messages table after clicking favorite button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a favorite button in my system. Each message has a favorite button, with the time the message was sent to the user. Now when a user favorites a button the time of the message is inserted into the `favorite_messages` table.

My problem is that for some reason the date column updates to the current date, which shouldn't update, it should stay the same as it is from when the message was sent.

Here is my php code:

```
$user_id = $_SESSION['active_user_id'];
extract($_GET);
$id=$_GET['message'];
$toggle = "yes";
$q=$db->prepare("SELECT msgid,date,text
    FROM messages 
    WHERE to_id=? and msgid=?");
$q->bindValue(1,$user_id);
$q->bindValue(2,$id);
$q->execute();
$row2=$q->fetch();
$d=$row2['date'];

$fav_questionq=$db->prepare("SELECT *
    FROM messages
    LEFT JOIN users
    ON messages.to_id=users.id
    WHERE users.id=? AND messages.msgid=?");
$fav_questionq->bindValue(1,$user_id);
$fav_questionq->bindValue(2,$id);
$fav_questionq->execute();
$frow=$fav_questionq->fetch();
$fquestion= $frow['text'];

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM fav_messages
                    WHERE username=? AND message=?");
$result->bindValue(1,$user_id); 
$result->bindValue(2,$id);              
$result->execute();

if($result->rowCount()== 1 )
{
    $updateMessageQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE messages SET toggle='no' WHERE msgid=?");
    $updateMessageQuery->bindValue(1,$id);
    $updateMessageQuery->execute();
    $deletequery=$db->prepare("DELETE FROM fav_messages WHERE message=?");
    $deletequery->bindValue(1,$id);
    $deletequery->execute();
} else {
    $updateMessageQuery = $db->prepare("UPDATE messages SET toggle='yes' WHERE msgid=?");
    $updateMessageQuery->bindValue(1,$id);
    $updateMessageQuery->execute();
    $insertquery = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO fav_messages (username,message,fav_question,fav_date) values(?,?,?,?)");
    $insertquery->bindValue(1,$user_id);
    $insertquery->bindValue(2,$id);
    $insertquery->bindValue(3,$fquestion);
    $insertquery->bindValue(4,$d);
    $insertquery->execute();
}
```

Here is my HTML favorite button code:

```
<a href="" class="msg-icon" onclick="toggle(this)"  >
    <input  type="hidden" name="fav"  value="<?php echo $row['msgid']; ?>" style=""  >

    <?php if($toggle=='yes'){ ?>
        <i class="fas fa-heart" id="favBtn" style="" ></i>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <i class="far fa-heart" id="favBtn" style="" ></i> 
    <?php } ?>
</a>
```

I figured out that the update queries I am making is causing the problem, but why would it update the date column when I am only specifying the toggle column?

Comment: Is your date column perhaps defined as `TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP`? What's the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE messages`?

Comment: yes default is current_timestamp

Comment: Does it have the `ON UPDATE` clause? If so, whenever you update a row in the table (regardless of which columns) then the date column will also update.

Comment: @Nick i updated my database table and changed the column date timestamp to default null. it fixed the problem. thank you so much for pointing it out!!!

Comment: No worries - I'm glad that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue has been resloved, problem was in the database, date type was timestamp and set to defualt current_timestamp, so on every update it would update to the current time. i set it to NULL and it fixed the problem

Comment: As explained in the comments, the problem is not the `DEFAULT`, but the `ON UPDATE`.

Comment: Yeah true, but removing the default value also fixed the problem

Comment: It is great that you solved your problem, but removing `DEFAULT` did not do it.  If you want to understand the issue, or make this answer useful for future visitors (it could even be you! :-)), take a minute to [read the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html), or some of the many [other examples here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18962757/when-is-a-timestamp-auto-updated/18962874), and update your answer.